# Background service on react-native android

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any way to create a background service with react-native on android?
I would like some sort of timer that wakes up every hour or so, and launches a simple javascript task.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I wanna know too: did you find any solution?

Comment: No but I had a workaround. I create the background service with java, which in turn calls some javascript code with  reactContext.getJSModule(...).emit('javascript_event_name', params)

It's a pity that there is no service available directly in the react-native API.

Comment: @andri but how do you call the javascript code if the main react app was closed for example ?

Comment: @delboud check my answer below for a JS only solution.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, It can be done.

React native operates on top of the native (java/Objc) to JS bridge with a concept of "native" and JS modules (modules can have methods that you may call from the "other" side of the bridge). All the UI stuff is built on top of the bridge (the main "native" module that handles generating views is called "UIManager"). It is possible to use bridge directly the only restriction is that the communication has to be asynchronous.

You can call the javascript function from the JAVA code. [Check this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) for the documentation.

Comment: Yes. That's what I ended doing. Too bad it's not included in the core API.

Comment: Hi @andri, could you be kind enough to share snippets in gist? or better if you have a repo for reference. :D

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely. In fact it's quite easy now to achieve this entirely in JS (no need to write native code) cross platform with [react native queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue#os-background-task-full-example) and [react native background task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task).

There are some limitations. The background task will only be fired roughly every 15 minutes at smallest intervals (and the timing isn't guaranteed to be perfect if it even fires at all - the iOS/Android scheduler is sort of a black box that looks at battery life, current cpu load, etc, when determining when to fire a scheduled task). Also the task is limited to 30 seconds of execution.

[I've written a tutorial on how to set all this up here](https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a).

Let me know if you have any difficulty getting it up and running.

Answer (score 10):

Release v0.36 support headless-js, only Android, for now.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html

Comment: Is it possible to call a native module's method in a headless task? 

Since the react bridge is "asleep" after some few time unplugged (doze mode) the native call from the JS seems to be pending until the device awake.

In my case I'd like to start playing the next track of a playlist (Javascript side) when my native player has finished the previous one. I'm using a headless task to notify the JS which try call "play(nextSong)" from my native module. But the native function is not executed until I wake the device up.

Answer (score 3):

It's Working in my case user the `react-native-background-job` library for running a background service. It's working after the kill the app.
https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job

```
import BackgroundJob from "react-native-background-job";
```

```js
const regularJobKey = "regularJobKey";

BackgroundJob.register({
  jobKey: regularJobKey,
  job: () => {
    
    console.log('Background Service Call!');

  }
});
```

```html
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => {
    BackgroundJob.schedule({
      jobKey: regularJobKey,
      period: 2000
    });
  }}
>
  <Text>Schedule regular job</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Example Here : https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job/blob/master/example/index.android.js

Comment: I want to call the web service, how can it's possible also set data inside the current view.

Comment: Hi, will it run when the phone is locked?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[react-native-background-actions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-actions),** it's very great service even for iOS and they are providing the ProgressBar feature as well.

```
yarn add react-native-background-actions
```

or npm:

```
npm install --save react-native-background-actions
```

A short code snippet of how to use it.

```
import BackgroundService from 'react-native-background-actions';
 
// You can do anything in your task such as network requests, timers and so on,
// as long as it doesn't touch UI. Once your task completes (i.e. the promise is resolved),
// React Native will go into "paused" mode (unless there are other tasks running,
// or there is a foreground app).
const veryIntensiveTask = async (taskDataArguments) => {
    // Example of an infinite loop task
    const { delay } = taskDataArguments;
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        for (let i = 0; BackgroundService.isRunning(); i++) {
            console.log(i);
            await sleep(delay);
        }
    });
};
 
const options = {
    taskName: 'Example',
    taskTitle: 'ExampleTask title',
    taskDesc: 'ExampleTask description',
    taskIcon: {
        name: 'ic_launcher',
        type: 'mipmap',
    },
    color: '#ff00ff',
    linkingURI: 'yourSchemeHere://chat/jane', // See Deep Linking for more info
    parameters: {
        delay: 1000,
    },
};
 
 
await BackgroundService.start(veryIntensiveTask, options);
await BackgroundService.updateNotification({taskDesc: 'New ExampleTask description'}); // Only Android, iOS will ignore this call
// iOS will also run everything here in the background until .stop() is called
await BackgroundService.stop();
```

Comment: This is not working if you minimize the application or terminating the application.

Comment: Yeah, same issue. any solutions ?