# Background service in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm using Firebase, while my app is in the background and i want to when the database has new data, the notification will be pushed, like this:

```
message.on('child_added', function(data) {
  pushNotification(data);
});
```

I have searched on Google and found this library:
https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job.

Everything works fine, my background job:

```
const newMessageJob = {
   jobKey: "newMessageJob",
   job: () => {
     pushNotification(newMessage);
   }
};
BackgroundJob.register(backgroundJob);
```

But the problem is here, it's only called at fixed times (looks like setInterval):

```
BackgroundJob.schedule({
  jobKey: "newMessageJob",
  period: 1000,
  timeout: 1000,
  exact: true
});
```

But i want it to work dynamically (Background Job fired when new data has been added), so how can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is way too broad. If you're using redux, you may do this with redux-saga, for example, or just by making your own simple middleware. If you don't want anything complicated, you can just set callback in componentDidMount and call setState. In react data travels only from parent to children, so you will need to lift this to the level where you can pass data as props to all components which need it. In many cases this would be topmost component.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to fire it while my app is in the background, and i'm using MobX, not Redux, how can i do that?

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood your problem initially. The first thing which comes to my mind is to do polling: push messages to queue on arrival and schedule a background job to fire every N milliseconds checking if there are unprocessed items in queue. There may be better solutions though.

Comment: Here you can get relevant help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687473/background-service-on-react-native-android/63972919#63972919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodic background tasks while the app is closed can be solved in pure JS (no native code needed) cross platform now with [react native queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue#os-background-task-full-example) and [react native background task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task), but what you are wanting to do (run an ongoing service in the background instead of a periodic task) is not possible in React Native currently (and there isn't even a general way to do this natively as far as I understand, apps use workarounds).

The current limitations on cross platform background tasks are as follows:

- The smallest interval of time between task execution is ~15 min.
- The background task has a timeout limit of 30 seconds.
- The task schedule is approximate. iOS/Android use battery life, current cpu load, etc to determine if a scheduled task can be executed or if execution should be delayed or even cancelled. It will generally run when you want it to, but don't expect the timing to be exact.

Comment: If you want to run a piece of code periodically even when the app is in the background you can certainly try react-native-background-task. It worked great on the Simulator but I couldn't get it to work on a real device.The disclaimer clearly said it's up to the OS to decide when to invoke your scheduled code, but all I want is to check for every 2 or 3 hours and iOS still didn't invoke it for a single time so far, and that's frustrating. It worked beautifully on the Simulator.

Comment: I've made use of react-native-background-task library in my app, but it didn't run the task that I set for being run regularly. Is it normal??

Comment: Yo can use react-native-background-fetch library. It works great in android,but  need to test in IOS