# React native background service

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, service, background

I am making a *react native app* and I want to fetch data from the Internet every 15 minutes. The approach I take must fetch the data in the background and work cross-platform. Is there a method for doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687473/background-service-on-react-native-android **duplicate**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background service on react-native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687473/background-service-on-react-native-android)

Comment: Here you can get relevant help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687473/background-service-on-react-native-android/63972919#63972919

Answer (score 0):

Use fetch api with **react-native-timer**

```
        import timer from 'react-native-timer';

        timer.setInterval("instanceName",function get() {
          return fetch(URL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseJson =>{
               console.log("json",responseJson) //set in state here
               })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("api call error", error);
              throw error;
            });
        },15*60*1000);

    timer.clearInterval(instanceName);
```