# How to Call API in Background or Kill State in React Native for Android?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a React Native project for Android, and I need to call an API even when the app is in the background or killed state. I want to ensure that certain data is fetched and updated in the background, possibly using a background service or some other method.

I've looked into various solutions and libraries, but I'm a bit lost on how to implement this effectively. Could someone please provide guidance or a step-by-step example on how to call an API in the background or when the app is in the killed state in React Native for Android?

I'd appreciate any insights, code examples, or best practices on how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background service on react-native android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687473/background-service-on-react-native-android)